# Angular 2-4 observable that comes from a click event

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a function that returns an `Observable` when a row in a table is clicked.

```
private onEnrollmentHistory(val: Enrollment[]) {
        this.enrollments = val;
        console.log(this.enrollments);
    }

    getEnrollmentHistoryById(id: number) {
        this.toggleMoreInfoDialog();
        return this.store.getEnrollmentHistoryById(id)
            .subscribe(
                this.onEnrollmentHistory
            );
    }
```

I'm not sure how to get this info into the component HTML.
I can't do `<div *ngFor="let enroll of someService | async">` because the ID isn't known until someone clicks on it.  Is there some syntax I'm missing to have some text in a div bound to this Observable?  something like
`<div (ngModel)="this.bSubject.getValue()">`?

the function is called from a table row

```
<td>
 (click)="getEnrollmentHistoryById(id)" class="fa fa-2x fa-info">
</td>


 <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         here are enrollments
          <div *ngFor="let e of enrollments">
                {{e}}
            </div>
       </div>
 </div>
```

This is meant to be read only, I just need grab something from the DB with the observable, and show it on the page on a click event.

Comment: pls post the html where `(click)` event is bound.

Comment: Quite unclear, since we have no idea of what you're trying to achieve. But how about `<div>{{ bSubject.getValue() }}</div>`. Not even sure why you use a BeahaviorSubject to store the value, instead of just storing the value in your component directly.

Comment: @JBNizet I added a little more context.  Basically I'm asking if there's an Angular way to remove the need for my onEnrollmentHistory function were I have a state variable to populate once the request is finished.  Even doing it  the way with the extra HTML I added I'm not seeing anything in the component HTML change, even though in the console the correct data is being set.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to add a variable to the component
`enrollmentHistory = new Observable<Enrollment[]>(null);`
and on the click event do

`enrollmentHistory = this.getEnrollmentHistoryById(id)`
and in the view
`<div *ngFor="let e of enrollmentHistory | async">` and this gave me what i needed.